# aptana studio 3 - Promote to Project not working with Sencha Touch 2.3 generated app's folder

Tags: sencha-touch, aptana, aptana3

I am trying to do a Promote to Project for a folder that was generated by Sencha Touch when I created a new app.

All I see is just the name of the project and expanding it, I see connections - but no other files. Although the folder has all the usual files

I can import other projects I have (python projects, etc) - but just not working for the Sencha Touch case.

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your folder has a file .project, delete that file and try to promote the folder to a project again.

Answer (score 0):

- Close Aptana Studio
- Locate the project folder on your computer
- Delete the ".metadata" folder.
- startup Aptana and try promoting the folder to project again

hope this helps anyone